# Based on Luke 3:22 & 1:39-41, Genesis 1:2, the 'Holy Spirit' was already here, so who does John 16:7, 16:13-14, John 14:26 talk about?

Tags: genesis, john-apostle, luke

I have seen some similar questions, however, this is slightly different.  The passages in John cannot be referring to the 'Holy Spirit' as it was here already, Jesus in John is talking about someone to come after him.

Luke 3:22 2 and the Holy Spirit descended on him in bodily form like a dove. And a voice came from heaven:

Luke chapter 1 verses 39-41:
And Mary rose in those days, and went into the hill country with haste, into a city of Juda; And entered into the house of Zacharias and saluted Elisabeth. And it came to pass, that, when Elisabeth heard the salutation of Mary, the babe leaped in her womb; and Elisabeth was filled with the Holy Ghost.

(Genesis 1:2) – from beginning of time - 1 In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth. 2 Now the earth was formless and empty, darkness was over the surface of the deep, and the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters.

"But I tell you the truth, it is to your advantage that I go away; for if I do not go away, the Paraclete (advocate) shall not come to you; but if I go, I will send him to you." John 16:7 also John 16: 12-14 and a number of other passages.

Jesus also mentioned as parakletos
1 John 2:1 Jesus is a parakletos (advocate), serving as a heavenly intercessor with the Father.

"And I will pray the Father, and He will give you another Paraclete, ["Paraclete" (Parakletos, Advocate, Comforter, Helper)] that he may abide with you into the age (to come)."John 14:16

John 1:20-24
20He did not refuse to confess, but openly declared, “I am not the Christ.” 21“Then who are you?” they inquired. “Are you Elijah?” He said, “I am not.” “Are you the Prophet?” 22So they said to him, “Who are you? We need an answer for those who sent us. What do you say about yourself?” 23John replied in the words of Isaiah the prophet: “I am the voice of one calling in the wilderness, ‘Make straight the way for the Lord.’” 24Then the Pharisees who had been sent 25asked him, “Why then do you baptize, if you are not the Christ, nor Elijah, nor the Prophet?”…
"2 Peter 1:21" - For prophecy never had its origin in the human will, but prophets, though human, spoke from God as they were carried along by the Holy Spirit; 
“John 15:26" - When the Advocate comes, whom I will send to you from the Father—the Spirit of truth who goes out from the Father—he will testify about me”. 
“Ephesians 4:30"  - And do not grieve the Holy Spirit of God, with whom you were sealed for the day of redemption. “Acts 4:31" - After they prayed, the place where they were meeting was shaken. And they were all filled with the Holy Spirit and spoke the word of God boldly.
"John 16:13" Howbeit when he, the Spirit of Truth, is come, he will guide you into all truth; for he shall not speak of himself; but what so ever he shall hear, that shall he speak: and he will show you things to come." 
John chapter 16: verses 7-8:
“Nevertheless I tell you the truth; it is expedient for you that I go away: for if I go not away, the Comforter will not come unto you; but if I depart, I will send him unto you. And when he is come, he will reprove the world of sin, and of righteousness, and of judgment.”

Comment: This question should be migrated to Biblical Hermeneutics SX

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to Stack Exchange Christianity. Enjoy your stay with us.

The Holy Spirit. along with the Father and Son, possesses every attribute of God. He, like them, is omniscient, omnipresent, omnipotent, immutable, and so much more.

As with the Son, however, the ***role*** of the Holy Spirit in salvation history has changed. ***He*** has not changed, but his role changed, ever since God chose to involve himself in the affairs of his creatures, particularly the human species, who bear his image. That is because prior to God's creative work, there was no such thing as history. God's plan of salvation existed from eternity in the eternal counsels of God.

Once the infinite and eternal God chose to ***enact*** salvation's plan (which was in God's mind a *fait accompli!*), he identified with his creatures in their finitude and their history over time, from the beginning to the very end, from

> "In the beginning God" (Genesis 1:1)

to

> "a new heaven and a new earth” (Revelation 21:1);

from an eternal kingdom which appeared in time to a kingdom which will extend into eternity; when

> "the kingdoms of this world have become the kingdom of our Lord and of his Christ, and he shall reign forever and ever" (Revelation 11:15).

All this to say, Christians should not be surprised that the Holy Spirit's involvement in the outworking of God's plan of salvation is a bit mysterious.

Prior to his coming in power on the day of Pentecost, when

> Suddenly a sound like the blowing of a violent wind came from heaven and filled the whole house where they were sitting [, and t]hey saw what seemed to be tongues of fire that separated and came to rest on each of them [, and a]ll of them were filled with the Holy Spirit and began to speak in other tongues as the Spirit enabled them (Acts 2:2-4),

the Holy Spirit's presence and power were manifest primarily through a chosen few who were temporally led and filled by the Spirit primarily in their roles as prophets, priests, and kings. Moreover, through a group even fewer in number, God's Spirit breathed out God's eternal written word (see 2 Peter 1:20-21, and 2 Timothy 3:16).

Only with the coming of the Holy Spirit on the day of Pentecost did he thereafter come to indwell God's chosen ones forever. Heretofore, the Spirit came upon people intermittently to accomplish what they could not accomplish in their own strength.

Often, that manifestation of the Holy Spirit involved miracles: from making a donkey able to talk (Numbers 22:18), to raising people from the dead (e.g., 1 Kings 17:17 ff.); from forth-telling God's word with exactitude (e.g., 1 Kings 17:14--"thus saith the LORD"), to foretelling God's word in exquisite detail (e.g., Isaiah 7:14; 9:6; and 53:1 ff.)

With his coming on Pentecost, true believers in Jesus Christ were regenerated and then baptized into the body of Christ (see Titus 3:4b-7). Jesus foretold of this recurring phenomenon to his disciples during Passion Week as a way to prepare them for his imminent--yet temporary--departure from Earth (John 14 and 16, passim).

In conclusion, the personhood of the Holy Spirit has been and will be the same from eternity past to eternity future. In helping to bring to pass the will of God, he adapted his *methodology* to temporal situations, but always according to an unchanging *theology*. Christians for centuries have taken their cues from the Holy Spirit as they are led by him to change and adapt their methodology in performing God's kingdom work here on earth. They also need, however, regardless of methods, to be in agreement with the Holy Spirit's goal of magnifying the person and work of their God and Savior, Jesus Christ, to the glory of God (e.g., John 16:15).

Comment: (+1). Very edifying. Your labour appreciated.

Comment: @NigelJ: Thanks for the encouragement, Nigel! Don

Comment: I agree with NigelJ - @rhetorician has done a great job here.

Comment: @rhetorician thank you for your detailed answer, the content has been noted.  However, this does not really answer the question.  The Holy Spirit has been here from the beginning, John 16:7 and others talk about someone to come.  Also says Paraclete / advocate / comforter / helper a person not the Holy Spirit.  The spirit will be given to the advocate.  Luke and Genesis 1:2 – clearly the Holy Spirit / spirit of God is already here from the beginning and while Jesus is here, not someone to come.  Your quotes re-affirm that the holy spirit was already here.  cont...

Comment: There is no issue with the Holy Spirit - Acts 2:2-4, 2 Peter 1:20-21 & 2 Timothy 3:16 & others only confirm that the Holy Spirit is already present and some are guided/given the holy spirit.  This is precisely what Jesus appears to be saying in John, that the spirit will be given to an advocate to come. This also fits with John 1:20-24 'art thou that prophet' added to body.  John 16:7 clearly says ‘the helper is yet to come’, talking about an advocate / person holy spirit already here and part and parcel of God / Jesus / son of man.

Comment: @Dottard - yes it might be better to move it to Biblical Hermeneutics - im not sure how to do it.

Comment: @anothertheory I think your reading too much into the text. Nothing is said about the spirit being given to another (singular). The spirit would come to indwell all who have faith in the Messiah and believe. This would be so they would have the wisdom, knowledge and power that Jesus had done (and more). Sure the Spirit would fill individuals for specific purposes, but this would become a permanent indwelling after the Pentecost event, hence the Spirit will come to dwell. No Gospel writer (or Jesus) said the Spirit wasn't already "here", he just wasn't here on a "permanent" basis yet.

Comment: @Herkfixer: Thaks for your comments. If I gave the impression in my answer that I believed the Spirit (i.e., the Holy Spirit) was given to just "another (singular)"--your words, I did not mean to. I agree with you that after Pentecost, the Holy Spirit came to indwell believers permanently. Just as we Christians can grieve the Holy Spirit and can quench the Holy Spirit, so also we can walk BY the Spirit, and be FILLED WiTH the Spirit. In each case, the Spirit is resident in us and does not come and go unpredictably.

Comment: @rhetorician I'm sorry, no I was commenting back to the OP not your post. Your post was accurate and succinct.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question. In researching for an answer I learned some quite interesting things. For example I learned that in your referenced Scriptures there were two separate comforters. The first being the reincarnate Christ and the other being The Holy Spirit. In the following paragraphs I reference Scriptures that lead me to that conclusion.

> John 14:16 through 20  And ***I will pray the Father***, and he shall give you ***another Comforter***, that **he may abide with you for ever**; Even the **Spirit of truth; whom the world cannot receive, because it seeth him not, neither knoweth him**: but *ye know him; for he dwelleth with you, and shall be in you*. ***I will not leave you comfortless: I will come to you***. 
>   John 14:19  Yet a little while, and the world seeth me no more; but ye see me: because I live, ye shall live also. At that day ye shall know that I am in my Father, and ye in me, and I in you.

Here we see that Jesus is referring to himself after he has conquered death by sacrificing himself as the son of man (or his human body) as sacrifice for the sins of the World. All sin for all time. We sere here that Jesus plans to pray to the father to send another comforter. He describes this other comforter as *the Spirit of truth*. He further identifies this other comforter as *ye know him; for he dwelleth with you, and shall be in you* (now that he has given them the truth it is a part of them forever). this is further elaborated in the following Scripture.

> John 10:36 through 38  Say ye of him, whom the Father hath sanctified, and sent into the world, Thou blasphemest; because I said, I am the Son of God? If I do not the works of my Father, believe me not. But if I do, though ye believe not me, believe the works: that ye may know, and believe, that the Father is in me, and I in him.

He further explains in:

> John 14:19 and 20  Yet a little while, and the world seeth me no more; but ye see me: because I live, ye shall live also. At that day ye shall know that I am in my Father, and ye in me, and I in you.

Here he tells us that in Eternity our spirits will combine with his.

> John 14:26  But the Comforter, which is the Holy Ghost, whom the Father will send in my name, he shall teach you all things, and bring all things to your remembrance, whatsoever I have said unto you.

This comforter unlike the Spirit of truth serves a different mission. His function is to educate and cause them to remember the things that Jesus taught them while here on Earth.

These are my conclusions from carefully studying those scriptures and in reference to some of my reference materials, such as David Guzik, F.B.Meyer and others.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response and your effort and that of rhetorician, much appreciated.  It appears there is an issue about interpretation of ‘Holy spirit’ ‘spirit of truth’ and ‘comforter’.  From the way I read it ‘holy spirit’ & ‘spirit of truth’ is something given to someone to go towards God (truth, strength, belief) which has been there from the beginning & comforter a person / prophet sent who will be given the ‘spirit of truth’. ‘To come after’ and ‘will not come until I leave’ are clearly talking about someone other than Jesus.  cont...

Comment: A comforter as a person with the spirit of truth.  There are many more verses, but a few;    Acts 5:32 We are witnesses of these things, and so is the Holy Spirit, whom God has given to those who obey him. see also added to the body - 2 Peter 1:21; John 15:26; Ephesians 4:30; Acts 4:31; John 16:13. John 16:7-8

Comment: should have added @BYE - doesn't seem to be letting me added @ at the beginning

Comment: @another theory - That's because any comment you post to a person who has answered your question automatically gets seen by same person. I've added @ here to ensure the comment gets flagged up in your C.Stack in-box.  Good question, bye the way!

Comment: @lesley thank you much appreciated, i wasn't sure if I was adding to many verses as there are so many.

Comment: @another theory as stated in my answer my opinion of two different spirits is primarily based on Jesus saying he would ask the father to send **another spirit** which is a request and his statement that the father would send the *Holy Spirit* which is more a statement of fact. Of course I am stating my opinion and do not state that it is fact, there is much that I do not know about the Bible and is why I continue to study it. again thank you for your question. Dissenting views are greatly appreciated.

Comment: @anothertheory "A comforter as a person with the spirit of truth." This is correct. Jesus is a human person anointed by the Holy Spirit the Spirit of Truth and became the Advocate. So the "another Advocate" is also a human person that received the anointing like Jesus to become the "another Advocate".

Comment: @BYE i dont think we ever stop learning lol.  If the 'holy spirit' was something different to what I said above - then the spirit of truth & comforter would have to be other then the holy spirit or Jesus - as it talks about 'coming after' - holy spirit from the beginning and Jesus was already there.

Comment: @ another theory Do not confuse the human Jesus with the eternal Spirit Jesus. The human Jesus was sacrificed for our sins. > John 20:17  ***Jesus saith unto her, Touch me not; for I am not yet ascended to my Father: but go to my brethren, and say unto them, I ascend unto my Father, and your Father; and to my God, and your God.*** and yet later that same day: > Joh 20:27  ***(Then saith he to Thomas, Reach hither thy finger, and behold my hands; and reach hither thy hand, and thrust it into my side: and be not faithless, but believing***.  continued

Comment: something happened between the morning and that night. That was Jesus ascending to the father and sacrificing his human body for our sins. Spirits do not die only humans do. Remember Jesus told his followers' > Joh 14:6  ***Jesus saith unto him, I am the way,***the truth***, and the life: no man cometh unto the Father, but by me***. I understand the Spirit of truth to be the eternal Jesus.

Comment: @BYE - I dont recall anywhere Jesus says he has a external spirit. John 20:17 - touch me not is he a spirit or not - why not touch?  issue interpretation of spirit and holy spirit.  However, ascend and spirit are 2 different things - if Jesus was resurrected then he would be spiritulised  - Latin Vulgate Luke 24:39 See my hands and feet, that it is I myself; handle, and see: for a **spirit hath not flesh and bones, as you see me to have**. cont...

Comment: Also he does not need to eat as you say cannt die again - 40 And when he had said this, he shewed them his hands and feet. 41 But while they yet believed not, and won-dered for joy, he said: Have you any thing to eat? 42 And they oﬀered him a piece of a broiled ﬁsh, and a honeycomb.  Why eat if you are a spirit?  Ascending is going up to God/heaven not making you a spirit.

Comment: @anothertheory again, you are reading too much into singular passages and not considering the wider context. In John 14:26 Jesus specifically calls the Comforter, the Holy Spirit. He does not say that the Comforter will recieve the Holy Spirit. He specifcially says that the "Comforter, (i.e.) the Holy Spirit, will be sent by God" for this purpose "teach you all things and remind you of everything I have told you." None of the verses you mentioned come anywhere near calling a person who HAS the Holy Spirit a comforter.

Comment: @anothertheory If anything, this is more Trinitarian language such as in John 16:12-15 you can see that Jesus is talking about things that HE has declared and said that will be brought his people through the HS. Calling the HS the Spirit of Truth, and Comforter are all ways the just describe the many roles of the HS. Its the same as when Jesus calls himself the Lord of the Sabbath, the Son of Man, the Son of God, Emmanuel, the Christ (no it wasn't his last name), the Logos (the Word).. etc. Each name or title just describes a different aspect, not a different person.

Comment: @Herkfixer thank you for your comments.  Before I respond just to confirm is your position that the Holy Spirit, spirit, spirit of truth, comforter/advocate etc are all 1 and the same Jesus?  Also **art thou that prophet** John 20:21, is that also the holy spirit?

Comment: @Herkfixer - sorry can you also clarify is the HS of God is the same as Jesus HS?

Comment: @Herkfixer - I just noticed your comment much higher up.  Do you also have any reference that the HS was not permanent from the beginning

Comment: As to your first question, yes but don't think of it as some octinity. They are merely nicknames. Its the same as saying John, AKA Funny Boy AKA Rabbit.. etc. They probably recieved the nicknames because they did something to earn the nickname. The HS is the Comforter because He comforts those who need it, He is the Spirit of Truth because He illuminates the Truth that Jesus brought, etc. The same goes for Jesus. He is Emmanuel, God with us because He dwells with humanity. He is the Son of Man because He is fully man and He is Son of God fully God. Just because you see different names ... cont

Comment: cont... doesn't mean they are different people. As for your reference to John 20:21, I'm not sure where you get that translation from but in that passage Jesus is telling them that He will give them the Holy Spirit and he said specifically... "Receive the Holy Spirit. 23 If you forgive the sins of any, they are forgiven them; if you retain the sins of any, they are retained." It was for a singular purpose. The Holy Spirit of Pentecost would give the disciples the Apostolic gifts of the Spirit. Just the fact that Jesus had to give them the Spirit again is showing that it was temporary ...cont

Comment: before. Remember that at the first commissioning they were filled with the Spirit to do those things and now Jesus is giving it to them again, and again on the Day of Pentecost. No one at all is saying that the HS was completely absent on Earth prior to Pentecost, but every time someone was filled with the HS in the past, it was for a specific purpose and a limited time. Because it is too long to post here, this link gives a really good discussion.  https://bible.org/question/how-did-holy-spirit-operate-lives-ot-saints

Comment: @Herkfixer thank you for your comments and links.  This does not prove your point, it seems more an interpretation to fit a point of view and opens up a lot of conundrums.  On that basis I have asked another question to clarify this point (see new question link below). https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/75895/are-spirit-spirit-of-truth-spirit-of-god-holy-ghost-dove-prophet-advocate-pri

Comment: @Herkfixer the link question was closed as this site doesn't appear to be appropriate to discuss a topic, but you will see the issue with your position.  from my understanding your view that Jesus becomes a holy spirit for all time when he ascends, is that right?  if so what about when he appears to Thomas when he is not a spirit?

Comment: @anothertheory No, you misunderstand. My view isn't that Jesus "becomes" a holy spirit. The Holy Spirit is a title and name of the third member of the Trinity. Jesus sends the Holy Spirit. When people say that Jesus is the Holy Spirit, it is in that all three (God, Jesus, Holy Spirit) are individual yet still one God. It is a very complicated concept because we have no examples in real life and all analogies break down but through Scripture we see this concept being developed through the passages we are talking about. Just search here for "Trinity" and you will get a plethora or resources.

Comment: @anothertheory this comment section really isnt the place to attempt to flesh out the Trinity as hundreds and thousands of volumes have been written in the attempt to explain it, which will not happen here.

Comment: @Herkfixer thanks for your comments, I did understand your position / Trinity my point was that it has to be consistent hence the bullet points I raised in the other question. The reason for so much to be written is to justify a position, over complicating something in my opinion that will never be able to be justified.  Obviously I hit a NERVE because I have been stopped from any more questions because of my above question for 6 months LOL. I thought just closing the question would have been sufficient - shows a shameful way some people are acting because it may be against their opinion.

Comment: @anothertheory It's not that you hit a nerve, its likely because you keep trying to ask the same question that has been closed repeatedly. First, the place to justify a position usually isn't in comments. Second, I have absolutely been consistent and to claim otherwise is gas-lighting. You keep misstating what Scripture, as well as myself, says. I have told you why the Spirit refers to a different "person" of the Trinity and not a descriptor of Jesus as a spirit himself. If you really aren't understanding the Trinitarian language then start your study there instead of repeating the same points

Comment: @Herkfixer We have our own opinions and that’s fine but being stopped had nothing to do with asking the same question but some people who don’t like my questions working together to stop me no justification. Wish you all the best.